# Publish Android App with leaderboards and no achievements

Tags: android, google-play-services, leaderboard, achievements

I have got my leaderboards integrated into my android app, but don't plan on adding achievements. I have completed the Game Services setup in the Developer console on Google Play, all apart from the achievements. When I go to the Publish section it says my achievements are missing. Is it possible to publish it without achievements?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Although you do need to put in some achievements (5 of them) for the Developers Console, they can just be markers, and not actually used in your code in any way.   Publish away!

Comment: Yea I gave up and did exactly that. I just made some achievements and published it and didn't bother putting them in the game code at all. I may add them at a later date though. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: How insane is this not?

Comment: Even though it seems strange, I guess the reason is that Google play game services keeps track of the user's XP according to XP earned by achievements.

There is no way to add XP to users without achievements so in order for a user to progress his level by playing your game, you must create some achievements and assign values.
https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/achievements#earning_experience_points_xp