# Google Game Services : Leaderboards only

Tags: android, google-play-games

For a game I'm developing, I'm setting up Google Play services. My game only needs leaderboards, so no achievements.

However, when setting up the game in Google Play, it told me that I needed to add at least 5 achievements.

Now, I can simply not link to the achievements popup in the game, but I'm not sure if that's a good thing to do. Maybe the achievements are visible somewhere else that I'm not aware of.

Any advice? (I could off course add the achievements, but I want to keep things simple, and if I can avoid an extra button to show the achievements, I'd prefer doing that).

Thanks!

Comment: the achievements will be visible in google play games which is on every android device pretty much! add achievements, their fun :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added 5 dummy achievements. I don't think there is away around it. The achievements won't show up unless you make them show up.

ps. 
[Publish Android App with leaderboards and no achievements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21957000/publish-android-app-with-leaderboards-and-no-achievements)